# How can I put name for column in R

Tags: r

I run this code

`for(i in 1:200){(if (p_values_SHtestt[i]>0.05){print(Rp[i,])})}`

then I get 3 separate columns as shown in the picture

but I want each column has name [,1], [,2], and [,3]

I used this code but did not get the desired result

[image]

Comment: you have to transform your "result" into a data frame to which you assigne your chosen names. as is you can not easily do it

Comment: Does this give the expected result: `Rp[p_values_SHtestt > 0.05, ]` ?

Comment: Try `print(RP[i, , drop = FALSE])`, but I agree with Aurèle that a `for` loop seems unnecessary.

Comment: many thanks for you all,   
Aurèle's code gives me the desired result